# Read a file as byte string from a Databricks ADLS mount point

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

The goal is to read a file as a **byte string** within Databricks from an ADLS mount point.

###### Confirming the ADLS mount point

Firstly, using `dbutils.fs.mounts()` it is confirmed to have the following:

`... MountInfo(mountPoint='/mnt/ftd', source='abfss://ftd@omitted.dfs.core.windows.net/', encryptionType=''), ...`

###### Confirming the existence of the file

The file under question is titled `TruthTable.csv`, its whereabouts have been confirmed using the following command:

`dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv')`

which returns:

`[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv', name='TruthTable.csv', size=156)]`

###### Confirming the readability of the file

To confirm that the file can be read we can run the following snippet.

```
filePath = '/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'
spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load(filePath)
```

which successfully returns

`DataFrame[p: string, q: string, r: string, s: string]`

###### The problem

As the goal is to be able to read a file as a byte string, the following snippet should be successful, however, it is not.

```
filePath = '/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'
with open(filePath, 'rb') as fin:
  contents = fin.read()
  print(contents)
```

Executing the following snippet outputs:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'`

The documentation provided by the Databricks team on the following link [https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis][https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-apis] works only for files found in the `/tmp/` folder, however, the requirement is the read a file directly from the mount point.

Answer (score 0):

Please add dbfs prefix:

```
filePath = '/dbfs/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'
with open(filePath, 'rb') as fin:
  contents = fin.read()
  print(contents)
```

For native databricks function (like dbutils) dbfs is used as default location.
When you access file system directly you need to add /dbfs which is default mount directory. Alternatively you can use 'dbfs:/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'. If you use free community edition it will not work at all as there is no access to underlying file system. For Azure, Aws and Google edition it should work.

Comment: I have in fact tried this approach, however, there is an exception. For instance, `dbutils.fs.ls('/mnt/ftd/MyServerType/MyServerName/LandingExperiments/dbo.SampleTsv/SampleTsv.txt')` confirms the existence of the file, but having `filePath = '/dbfs/mnt/ftd/MyServerType/MyServerName/LandingExperiments/dbo.SampleTsv/SampleTsv.txt'` results in a `FileNotFoundError`.

It seems that the mount point cannot access the contents as easily when multiple nested folders are involved in the path.

Also, I have access to the paid version of Azure Databricks.

Comment: please try magic command to validate folder structure step by step with shell also

%sh
ls /
ls /dbfs/mnt/ftd/MyServerType/MyServerName/LandingExperiments/dbo.SampleTsv/
etc.

Comment: After executing multiple ls commands, traversing folder by folder, starting from the root, the Python open file code executes successfully. However, this is an approach that I have discovered previously. I found an error in my code that simulates this `ls`-based traversal before executing the open-file Python code. I will continue testing the reliability of this approach, because this does not seem a 100% reliable.

Comment: can you add the final working code as answer to your own question? I have the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the file by replacing the **s3a://** and bucket prefix, to the corresponding **/dbfs/mnt/** one.

> s3a://s3-bucket/lake/output/dept/2022/09/16/20220916_1643_764250.csv
> /dbfs/mnt/output/dept/2022/09/16/20220916_1643_764250.csv

I used this:

```
_path = _path.replace('s3a://s3-bucket/lake', '/dbfs/mnt')
```

Hope it helps.

-ed

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code:

```
filePath = '/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'
spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load(filePath)
```

to

```
filePath = '/mnt/ftd/TruthTable.csv'
df=spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').load(filePath)

display(df)
```

Should show the file as final output.